# Non-trivial representation of second-smallest dimension

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Hi,
The complex simple algebraic group $Sp_{m,\mathbb{C}}$ of $2m$-dimensional space $V$ has, for $m≥2$, an irreducible representation of dimension $m(2m−1)−1$ in a subspace of codimension $1$ of the space $\Lambda^2V$. Is it the irreducible representation of smallest dimension after $V$ itself?

Thank you.

Comment: It follows from the Weyl dimension formula that the fundamental representations have minimal dimensions. So you only have to check the dimensions of these.

Comment: Well, minimal was not the right word. What I meant to say that the representation with minimal dimension among all representations is the same as the representation which has the smallest dimension amongst fundamental representations.

Comment: @robot: OP wants to know the *second* smallest dimension of a nontrivial irreducible representation of a group of type $C_m$.

Comment: The question itself just involves classical ideas, so it might be answered in the literature(?); anyway it's really about the Lie algebra, which may be a tag to add.   As robot observes, Weyl's dimension polynomial gives bigger values for non-fundamental weights.   The fundamental irreducibles are close to the exterior powers, with dimensions given as a difference of two binomial coefficients.   A quick calculation for `$m=3$` gives (I hope)` dimensions 6, 14, 14, but after that the later ones grow faster.   Presumably the answer to your question is yes, but it needs an argument.   

Comment: The answer is yes, see my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118472/transitive-action-on-the-sphere/118581#118581.

Comment: There would be less confusion if the title of this question was "Representation of third-smallest dimension" ;-) [if we're counting the trivial 1-d rep -- and why not?]

Comment: You are right, it is better the title to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The irreducible complex representations of the  simply connected simple group $G=Sp_{r,{\mathbb C}}$ of type $C_r$,
for $r>1$, of dimension $n<{\rm dim}\ G$
are listed in the [paper of Andreev, Vinberg, and Elashvili](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF01076005),
Table 1 (see also the [Russian version](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/419af2a1d9d33839a49ff8898866b056/faa2839.pdf)). 
They are the fundamental irreducible representations $R(\pi_1)$ of dimension $2r$, $R(\pi_2)$ of dimension $2r^2-r-1$,
and, for $r=3$, $R(\pi_3)$ of dimension 14. 
For all $r\ge 2$, $r\neq 3$, we have ${\rm dim}\ R(\pi_1)=2r<2r^2-r-1={\rm dim}\ R(\pi_2)$, 
hence $R(\pi_2)$ is the nontrivial irreducible representation of second smallest dimension.
For $r=3$,  as Jim Humphreys noted, the dimensions are $6,14,14$, so ${\rm dim}\ R(\pi_2)={\rm dim}\ R(\pi_3)>{\rm dim}\ R(\pi_1)$, and 
$R(\pi_2)$ is *a* nontrivial irreducible representation of second smallest dimension.

Comment: @Gabriel-Kj: Since you have accepted my answer and have thanked Jim, 
you can also vote up both answers...

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful to expand my comments.   The question involves Lie type $C_m$ with $m \geq 2$.   Without developing Lie group or algebraic group language, it's enough to work with a simple Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ of this type.    Using the standard numbering of vertices in the Dynkin diagram, let $E_i$ be the fundamental representation of highest weight $\varpi_i$ for $i= 1, \dots, m$.  Here $E_1$ is the standard module of dimension $2m$.   For the others, there are numerous classical references.   There is a thorough discussion of the construction in Bourbaki *Groupes et algebres de Lie* (also in English translation), Chap. VIII, $\S13$, no. 3, (IV).   In particular, the well-known dimension formula is made explicit:

$$\dim E_i = \binom{2m}{i} - \binom{2m}{i-2} \text{ for } i \geq 2$$.

Clearly $\dim E_1 > \dim E_2$.   The claim is that $\dim E_2 \geq \dim E_j$
for all $j >2$.   This should require an elementary combinatorial comparison, not involving any Lie theory, though it would be interesting to see a conceptual argument.

Granted this inequality, Weyl's dimension formula (as already noted) will complete the desired argument for $ E_2$ being the second smallest nontrivial irreducible representation.    The formula involves a fraction, whose denominator can be ignored.  The numerator is an integral polynomial in the highest weight, which obviously grows larger as the coordinates of that weight increase relative to the $\varpi_i$.

P.S. I don't want to leave the impression that I've written down a formal proof.   It's only a proof-scheme, but should be fairly easy to complete using straightforward methods.   For the comparison between fundamental and non-fundamental weights, you'd need to look at the root system $C_m$ (say at the end of Chapters IV-VI of Bourbaki): a rough comparison of how often $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ occur in each positive root shows for instance how the Weyl dimension for $2\varpi_1$ exceeds the dimension for $\varpi_2$, etc.    I don't recall seeing all of this written down anywhere, but if there is motivation to do so it should be elementary to complete.

Comment: @Gabriel-Kj: I don't have ready access to the paper cited by Mikhail, so was giving a more hands-on approach to the question.    In any case, it might be appropriate to upvote at least one of our answers ;-)   (Though I did resolve quite recently to avoid all future use of smileys.)

Comment: @Jim: You can find the Russian version for free in http://www.mathnet.ru/links/419af2a1d9d33839a49ff8898866b056/faa2839.pdf . There is just a table, no details of calculations.

Comment: @Mikhail: The question and the two answers was very helpful for me. Thanks to all of you. As you said there is no details to the table in the cited article. Could you tell me where I can find some details to the table. I need to check possibility of some embeddings like the question.

Comment: P.S. I'm also curious about details of the method used for the theorem in the 1967 note; that journal had very tight length limiutations, frustrating many readers. I'd also emphasize that the question and my sketched answer are much more elementary: you don't need to know about Lie groups, algebraic groups, geometry.   The Cartan-Weyl theory for Lie algebras is probably enough here, but the orbit dimension questions are independently interesting. 

Comment: @Nerd-Math: I don't think you can find details in the literature. You have to perform the calculations yourself! You can find useful formulas for dimensions of certain irreducible representations in Table 5 of the book "Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups" by Onishchik and  Vinberg (again, given without proofs).

Comment: @Mikail: I'm sorry if here is not appropriate for the question: I need to know (without details) which of the four representations of $A_r$ ($A_r=SU(r+1)$) in that table is trivial on the center, specially the first representation which is of dimnension $r+1$, is it trivial on the center? thanks

Comment: @Nerd-Math: For split groups (and I guess compact groups), it's easy to decide via the highest weight, with triviality on the center iff the weight is in the root lattice.  In your example, usually not.